# How to set up Steam Link?

Tags: windows-10, tv, steam-link

I recently got the Steam link but its specification is not really helpful. There is just a diagram without any description what to do.

From what I can figure from the diagram, I'm guessing I'm either supposed to plug my PC directly into the house modem, and my Steam Link into my TV,  or vice versa...

Problem is, my PC, TV, and the house modem are all in entirely different rooms and are too far away to connect via cable.
I can't move the modem to another room.

Does anyone here know a way I could set this up wirelessly without moving the modem or other things closer together?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Have you tried plugging the Link into the TV and powering it on?

Comment: Steam Link does WiFi. Have it connect the same WiFi as your PC. Case closed.

Answer (score 1):

For any questions about the steamlink, you could visit the [Steamlink support page](https://help.steampowered.com/en/wizard/HelpWithGame/?appid=353380) or [this short steamlink setup guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=706596377). Basically, if your PC and steamlink are connected (wireless or wired) to the same network/modem, they can see each other and connect (if you don't have any firewall or config within steam to prevent this).

All in all, you can play games via wireless, but the official page and countless other sources do not recommend the wireless setup due to latency and servere signal interference. This however, can be mitigated a bit by setting up the wireless band to 5Ghz in stead of 2.4Ghz.